# how to sync files in linux - command prompt?

Tags: filesystem, sync, rsync

I see the following files in my directory -

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  401 Oct 12 15:29 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  401 Oct 12 15:29 Makefile~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  336 Oct 12 15:12 testIfaceIndex.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  336 Oct 12 15:12 testIfaceIndex.c~
```

My question is how can I get rid of the file Makefile~ and testIfaceIndex.c~?
I have tried the command sync on the folder but it didn't work. how can I sync the files? What is the complete command to do so?

Comment: What's your goal? Delete the files? Exclude the files from rsync. Avoid the creation of the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sync` command flush file system buffers. for more info about sync see

```
man sync
```

When you use `gedit` as a editor then gedit create these file. These files are backup file of your original file with name `~`. you can disable this in preference setting of gedit.
change 
[image]

To

[image]

and reduce `Autosave` time. next time it will not create backup file.